# Asp.net MVC parse url parameter to object using [FromUri]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, url, kendo-ui

Currently I'm struggeling with some `Url-Parameter`. I try create an object from the following url:

`../Data/GetOrderList?take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort[0][field]=Password&sort[0][dir]=asc`

Which works pretty will except, the *sort* part. My method looks like this: `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrderList([FromUri]Models.GridParameter model)`

The problem is the `GridParameter` class, where `sort` should be a property in. But I don't knwo how to represent this part `&sort[0][field]=Password&sort[0][dir]=asc` as an object.

Does someone solved this issue before?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using For ASP.NET MVC 5, not WebAPI right?
The easiest but not nicest way would be to read query string parametrs from `Request.QueryString` in your action method.

You can also write your own [ModelBinderAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class and parse Query string there, that would be much cleaner solution.