# How to specify custom URL parameter names?

Tags: asp.net, .net, url

In an ASP.NET route, I can use the `FromUri` attribute to indicate that an argument should be taken from the URL parameters of the request. In the case of a complex object, ASP.NET will conveniently take the values of the individual properties from the parameters:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("getvalue")]
public string getValue([FromUri] MyData args)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, our styleguide requires web API parameters to be camelCased, whereas C# object properties should be PascalCased.

**How can I tell ASP.NET to use custom names (`"value1"` and `"value2"` in the above example) for the web API parameters rather than the property names?**

EDIT: To be clear, the resulting URL format is fixed: My route has to serve requests like

```
.../getvalue?value1=15&value2=43
```

With the above code, I'm almost there, but the request still has to be

```
.../getvalue?Value1=15&Value2=43
```

Hence, my question is how to specify `value1` and `value2` as URL parameter names instead of `Value1` and `Value2`, respectively, *without* changing the names of the C# properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this.

```
[HttpGet("dosomething/{value1}/{value2}")]
public void DoSomething(int value1, int value2)
{
    // ...
}
```

You *could* do some messing around with query parameters, but I don't think you can do object mapping in the URL itself.

If you're aiming for a RESTful API, you should think about how value1 and value2 relate to each other, and order the URL accordingly (eg, in the order of my example, it should make sense to "get" the url: "dosomething/value1", and it should return less specific data than "dosomething/value1/value2")

Comment: Sorry, it's not supposed to be a dynamic route. The resulting URL must be structured like `.../dosomething?value1=5&value2=10` (with the order of parameters exchangeable, of course).

Comment: Are you supposed to get data back? "DoSomething" sounds like it might be a decent candidate for a POST/PUT command.

Comment: Yes, the actual method retrieves some information. I omitted the return value for the sake of simplicity, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you're asking. I've never done this personally, but this looks like what you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332310/asp-net-mvc-parse-url-parameter-to-object-using-fromuri